# Unable to launch tortoise hg in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mercurial

I have installed tortoise hg in Ubuntu 18.04.4 using the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install tortoisehg
```

I also tried installing it through Ubuntu software centre. It's getting installed without any issues. But I'm not able to launch it. Can anyone help me with this?

When running `thg` in terminal, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/bin/thg", line 31
    print 'starting'
                   ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('starting')?
```

output for `which python`:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

output for `which python2`:

```
/usr/bin/python2
```

output for `which python3`:

```
/usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: How do you try to launch it ? Do you get any error ?

Comment: No i don't get any error. I am able to search and find the app. But when i click on the tortoisehg icon, it doesn't launch.

Comment: Please open terminal and execute `thg` command in it. The please add possible error output to the question by [pasting it on edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1287309/edit).

Comment: Please show the output of `which python2`, `which python`, `which python3`.

Comment: @N0rbert all are in the path /usr/bin as you can see above

Comment: I would recommend to reinstall the package by `sudo apt-get install --reinstall tortoisehg` .

Comment: @N0rbert I tried now. Again bad luck :(

Comment: On fresh installation I can't reproduce the issue, so there is some misconfiguration here. I tried to open `/usr/bin/thg` in text editor and see that this code fragment is not related to linux version of Thg. Let's check some info about your current environment - please execute in the terminal two commands - `python -c "import sys; print hasattr(sys,'frozen')"` and `echo $THGDEBUG` . What is your current desktop and terminal?

Comment: The output for the command python -c "import sys; print hasattr(sys,'frozen')"  is false. echo $THGDEBUG doesn't return anything. I'm using a dell laptop, GNOME terminal

Answer (score 1):

Had this exact problem with same error message. Try starting the program with: `python2 /usr/bin/thg`. That solved things for me.